# not able to align vertical flex-end on IE11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

Regarding [this in desktop view](http://p262955.mittwaldserver.info/wordpress/nh-grafik-in-html/), I have difficulties to bring the svg triangles on the top of the green stacks to their vertical `flex-end` on IE11, see screen capture. Chrome and others work properly.

[image: triangles should sit directly on the stacks]

I tried some ideas that I got from [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), but I wasn't able to get it working. Bootstrap 3 is present. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Additional code to the one linked on line 1 of my post? Or do you want me to cut it out as a snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all style of `.tg-nh-rating-table svg` and add

```
.tg-nh-rating-table svg {
    height: 50px;
}
```

It seem IE11 realize `svg` is 100%, the same height with wrap div `pylon-end`. So just add height for svg. This will work.

Comment: Thanks :) But i tried to avoid this because the fixed height crashes the display when the browser windows widths scales down. But when fixed heights are working, i could try to determine the correct height with a javascript. Or do you have another idea?

Comment: You can go with min-height, ad use media query to adjust when browser is small.